# Java, Scala, Groovy и проч. что выбрать для разработки десктопа?

Tags: groovy, desktop, java, scala

Есть запрос на написание десктопного мультиплатформенного приложения. Условие язык должен быть на платформе Java.

Писать надо быстро, так что надо чтобы язык имел приличную гуйную библиотеку.

Что посоветуете?

По C/C++/Perl и проч. просьба не умничать. У приложения есть довольно большой набор Java библиотек с бизнес-логикой, так что платформа строго Java - вариантов нет.

Comment: А зачем Вы спрашиваете? Судя по Вашему рейтингу - Вы и так все знаете! Но если хотите ответ, то на платформе Java используйте язык Visual Basic 6. Не прогадаете!

Comment: месье знает толк в извращениях

Comment: Высокий рейтинг не гарантирует полноты знаний... Ну а вашу шутку я оценил :)

Comment: По поводу *"вариантов нет"*. 

Можно разделить бизнес логику на java и пользовательский интерфейс *на чем удобнее* на 2 процесса и связать их, например, через сокет.

Одновременно получаете задел для распределенной обработки. Лет через 5 выстрелит.

Comment: @avp - я подумаю, интересное предложение

Comment: я б написал свой маленький движочек, - правда в enterprise вряд-ли кто-то на это пойдет. 

Eclipse RCP вам не подходит?

Comment: Kotlin - лучший выбор

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Сами по себе `Scala` и `Groovy` пока не содержат в себе отдельных `production-ready` решений для `GUI`, кроме оберток над `swing`.

> При этом вариантов, вообще говоря, два - [**SwingBuilder**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GUI+Programming+with+Groovy) для `Groovy` и [**scala.swing**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/package.html) для `Scala`.

- Если вы хорошо знакомы с `Groovy / Scala` *(и если вы не единственный из команды, кто может этим похвастаться)*, то можете воспользоваться одним из этих подходов.

> При этом, очевидно, стоит учитывать время на необходимость разобраться в деталях соответствующих оберток и возможные риски из-за их *непродуманности* или *недоделанности.* Очень обидно будет нарваться на `UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")` в конце спринта.

- Если нет, а выбор между `vanilla Java / Scala / Groovy` появился только благодаря *"модности"* последних, то работайте через них с `java.swing`, либо вообще остановитесь на просто `Java`.

> Лично я, не будь у меня как минимум года работы со `Scala / Groovy / Clojure / Kotlin`, не стал браться за разработку бизнес-решения на их базе.

Comment: Vanilla Java - это 5! Придется в руки брать старый добрый Java Swing

Comment: Есть еще сомнительного вида обертки ScalaFX и GroovyFX. Но я их ни в коем случае не рекомендую )

Comment: Всем спасибо взял в руки Swing - тем паче есть замечательный конструктор под Netbeans'ом

Answer (score 3):

Наткнулся сегодня на *dzone* на номер журнала *Java* *Tech* *Journal*, посвященный Groovy, а уже в нем на статью о Grails-подобной платформе для десктопных приложений **Griffon**.

Что дают (если верить статье):

- Набор утилит командной строки для создания проекта, сборки, упаковки и деплоя
- MVC
- Bindings для свойств бинов
- различные реализации непосредственно GUI (Swing, SWT, JavaFX)
- расширяемость плагинами
- Convention over Configuration, управление структурой и жизненным циклом приложения

В общем, если есть тяга к экспериментам, я бы взглянул.

Comment: groovy + griffon имхо!
Изучите groovy, не пожалеете. Легкий, быстрый в изучении

Answer (score -7):

Если надо быстро написать десктопное мультиплатформенное приложение,  сегодня это возможно только на Lazarus+freepascal, который к тому же очищает совесть своим openSource.
Слова  "быстро написать", "java" и "мультиплатформенное приложение" не вяжутся.
Сказки про java просто хорошо раскручены.

Comment: Увы, сказки про [free]pascal были раскручены в прошлом тысячелетии, и сейчас уже мало кто их помнит.

Comment: Сложно спорить с зомби

Comment: А зомби -- это кто? Lazarus? Так умереть-то оно, благодаря достаточно большому количеству кода и малограмотности преподавателей (паскаль на младших курсах есть, а вот умения пользоваться логарифмической линейкой уже нет), ещё не умерло. Так что ещё не зомби -- так, "умирающий лебедь". Недобиток.

Comment: Давайте не разводить флуд. 
Я ответил достаточно точно и конкретно на вопрос.
А то что Вам  кому - то что-то не нравиться дело вкуса.
Я своих подчиненных обучаю просто-

1-программирование для ускорения анализа юзера, а не для словоблудия используя малопонимаемые термины
Я готов сесть с Вами - дать штатную ежедневно ежечасную задачу и дать Вам всеп возможные инструменты java - но времени от 5 -20 минут - на выходе

Comment: @Alexmai

- Флуд никто и не разводит. Вы, в принципе, можете обучать своих подчиненных каким угодно *просто-1-программированиям для ускорения анализа юзера*, но вы просто **не сумели прочитать вопрос**, где совершенно четко указано, что имеется `dependency` на некоторый набор `Java` библиотек, реализующий бизнес-логику приложения.

- Очевидно, что это условие делает ваш ответ про `freepascal` совершенно бессмысленным.

Comment: Тезис о том, что Lazarus  - единственное кроссплатформенное решение, просто смешён.